# C# convert IEnumerable to Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code :

```
private static List<ParticipantJson> GetListParticipants(string dossierJson)
{
  dynamic participantsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(dossierJson);
  IEnumerable<ParticipantJson>[] myList = participantsJson.Participants.ToString() as IEnumerable<ParticipantJson>[];
  var list = myList.ToList();
  return null;
}
```

the part of `participantsJson.Participants.ToString() as IEnumerable<ParticipantJson>[];`
in debugging mode shows the two json objects of the table Participants[0] and Participants[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH6I3.png). as the next image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH6I3.png)

but the affectation IEnumerable[] myList is null.

How do i mess ?

Comment: Firstly, you're declaring an array of IEnumerable, not just an IEnumerable. Secondly, you call ToString, which returns a string, and then you try to cast that as a completely different type. It's a string, so why would you expect it to be able to be cast as that type?

Comment: `participantsJson.Participants.ToString() as IEnumerable<ParticipantJson>[];` is part of your problem. `ToString` returns a **string** representation of an object. Not anything that could be an array, or an enumerable, or anything other than `string`. Break the code down into individual pieces and use a debugger to step through line by line and look at what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried to do `return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParticipantJson[]>(dossierJson)`?

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you stay away from `dynamic` if at all possible. There are ways of parsing your JSON and grabbing the Participants array without using dynamic.

Comment: this code ParticipantJson[] participantsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParticipantJson[]>(dossierJson); doesnt work

Comment: i think i'm little bit close to fix the issue.
the problem is here : How to 
assign aparticipantsJson.Participants as IEnumerable<ParticipantJson>; to the right list type to return it.

Comment: ToString() is not the problem

Comment: ToString absolutely is a problem, as is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned using dynamic is not the best practice to deserialize json objects. Especially since .NET allows you to create classes that json can be mapped to.

```
public class ParticipantsJson
{
  public List<ParticipantJson> Participants { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantJson
{
  public int DeltaParticipant { get; set; }
  //... remainder of JSON fields from JToken section in image
}

private static List<ParticipantJson> GetListParticipants(string dossierJson)
{
  var participantsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParticipantsJson>(dossierJson);
  return participantsJson.Participants;
}
```

That said you can still use `dynamic` in your function.

```
private static List<ParticipantJson> GetListParticipants(string dossierJson)
{
  dynamic participantsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(dossierJson);

// this creates an array which to access you would need to loop through each object using a for loop.

var myList = new List<ParticipantJson>();

for(int i = 0; i < participantsJson.Count(); i++)
{
  var newParticipant = new ParticipantJson {
     DeltaParticipant = participantsJson[i].DeltaParticipant,
     //... remainder of JSON fields from JToken section in image
  };
  myList.add(newParticipant);
}

// or using foreach loop

foreach(var participant in participantsJson)
{
   var newParticipant = new ParticipantJson {
   DeltaParticipant = participant.DeltaParticipant,
     //... remainder of JSON fields from JToken section in image
   };
   myList.add(newParticipant);
}

  return myList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i found The solution. I think it have the same aspect as Yours

Answer (score 0):

finally this code works for me.

```
private static List<ParticipantJson> GetListParticipants(string dossierJson)
{
  dynamic participantsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(dossierJson);

  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray myList = participantsJson.Participants;
  var jTokens = myList.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
  List<ParticipantJson> participants = new List<ParticipantJson>();
  foreach (var token in jTokens)
  {
    ParticipantJson _tmp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParticipantJson>(token);
    participants.Add(_tmp);
  }
  return participants;
}
```

I fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).